# iterator with parent/child processes inside connected by pipe not incrementing properly

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, fork

Very simple college code (Operational Systems class) to make the parent process read from string, then child process write the string, while using pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int nDadosTx, nDadosRx;
    int size = 2;
    const char textoTX[] = "roger roger!";
    char textoRX[sizeof(textoTX)];
    int fd[size][2];
    
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {

        if (pipe(fd[i]) < 0)
        {
            puts("Erro ao abrir os pipes.\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
        
                    close(fd[i][0]); 
                    nDadosTx = write(fd[i][1], textoTX, strlen(textoTX)+1);
        
                    if (nDadosTx != strlen(textoTX)+1)
                    { 
                        printf("Tamanhos da mensagem incompativeis: %d, %d.\n", nDadosTx, strlen(textoTX)+1);
                        exit(1);
                    }
        
                    printf("%d dados escritos\n", nDadosTx);
            
                    printf("Droid %d a postos.\n------\n", i);

            }
            else
            {
                close(fd[i][1]);
                nDadosRx = read(fd[i][0], textoRX, sizeof(textoRX));
                printf("%d dados lidos: %s\n", nDadosRx, textoRX);
            }

        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        i++;

    }
    
    /*for (int i = 0;  i < 6; i++)
    {
        close (fd[0]);
        close (fd[1]);
    }*/
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the program executes just 1 time ok, but adding iteration:
2 iterations:
i = 0
normal print
i = 1
normal print
i = 1
normal print
(yes, again)

3 iterations:
i = 0
normal print
i = 1
normal print
i = 2
normal print
i = 2
normal print
i = 1
normal print
i = 2
normal print
i = 2
normal print

What's up?
gcc 10.1.0

Comment: Please show the **exact** output from your program as well as the expected output.

Comment: One issue is that the child processes are also running the code that only the parent should run - e.g the child processes also call `waitpid` and then `fork` on the next iteration. The child code path should `exit` or `return` prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

"One issue is that the child processes are also running the code that only the parent should run - e.g the child processes also call waitpid and then fork on the next iteration. The child code path should exit or return prior to that. – @kaylum 5 mins ago "

#include <sys/types.h>

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); in the end of the child did it.